# No aparece mi anuncio Admob (cordova-plugin-admob-free) en aplicación híbrida javascript

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

buenos días.

Estoy terminando el desarrollo de una aplicacióni híbrida para las plataformas iOS y Android a la que le quiero poner un banner de Admob. Por ahora la aplicación la estoy probando en dispositivos Android, hasta que no recupere parte de lo invertido no lo sacaré en iOS.

El caso es que no consigo que aparezca el banner que creé en la herramienta de Admob. Solo aparece el banner cuando uso el ID de prueba, de testing.

Hace semanas que creé el banner en Admob, al principio pensé que podría ser porque tardara algo de tiempo en aparecer, pero pasan los días y jamás aparece.

No utilizo ningún framework. Solo Javascript y HTML, todo encapsulado con cordova.

Entiendo que el plugin cordova-plugin-admob-free está bien instalado ya que sí aparecen los banner de testing. Lo instalé indicando el ID de mi aplicación de Admob.
Utilizo el mismo código que hay de ejemplo en el plugin cordova.

```
var admobid = {}
if (/(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {  // for android & amazon-fireos
    admobid = {
        bannerTesting: 'ca-app-pub-6915871454703626/7136560791',
        bannerMio : 'ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXX',
        banner: 'ca-app-pub-6915871454703626/7136560791',
        interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY/YYYYYYYYYY',
    }
} else if (/(ipod|iphone|ipad)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {  // for ios
    admobid = {
        banner: 'ca-app-pub-WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW/ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ',
        interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-WWWWWWWWWWWWWWW/WWWWWWWWWWWWW',
    }
}

document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
    admob.banner.config({
        id: admobid.banner,
        isTesting: false,
        autoShow: true,
    })
    admob.banner.prepare()

    admob.interstitial.config({
        id: admobid.interstitial,
        isTesting: true,
        autoShow: false,
    })
    admob.interstitial.prepare()

/*
    document.getElementById('showAd').disabled = true
    document.getElementById('showAd').onclick = function() {
        admob.interstitial.show()
    }
*/

}, false)

document.addEventListener('admob.banner.events.LOAD_FAIL', function(event) {
    console.log(event)
})
```

¿alguien me puede orientar para encontrar solución al problema?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido al sito ... !!! te doy la bienvenida y te invito a que realices el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Además revisa [ask] que te da información para realizar una buena pregunta y de esta forma obtengas buenas respuestas!. ¿se despliega algún error? saludos.

Comment: Hola, bienhallado.

llevo muchos años al otro lado, jejeje.
No se despliega ningún error. Simplemente no se ve.